# Grouping by attribute of associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

How to write mysql query to search all events `group_by` meeting `DATE(start_at)`?

```
Event.inludes(:meetings).group ...
```

As a result I want to get a `Hash`:

```
{"2014-01-24"=>[#<Event id: , title: "First", created_at: "2014-01-24 16:02:52", updated_at: "2014-01-24 16:02:52">, #<Event id: 2, title: "Second", created_at: "2014-01-24 16:02:52", updated_at: "2014-01-24 16:02:52">], "2013-01-29"=>[#<Event id: 3, title: "Third", created_at: "2013-01-29 05:30:40", updated_at: "2014-01-29 05:30:40">], ...]}
```

P.S: I am using `PostgreSQL`

Now I get it by this way:

```
hash = {}
Meeting.where("extract(month from start_at) = ?", Date.today.month).pluck('DATE(start_at)').uniq.each do |date| 
  hash[date] = Event.includes(:meetings).where("DATE(meetings.start_at) = ?", date).references(:meetings)
end
```

But it produced so many queries to the database :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event.joins(:meetings).group('meetings.start_at') should do. But want you want is a group_by array method http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by so what you should do is

@events.group_by {|e| e.meeting.start_date}

In case of many to many you should be better off with

```
result = Hash.new
Meeting.include(:events).each {|m| result[m.start_at]||=[]; result[m.start_at] << m.events}
```

and with one liner you could

```
Meeting.includes(:events).inject(Hash.new) do |result, m|
  result[m.start_at]||=[]
  result[m.start_at] << w.events
  result
end
```

This code should execute two database calls i think

Comment: Well in that case maybe it will better if you fetch all meetings with associated events (:includes) and then do 

result = Hash.new; @meetings.each{|m| result[m.start_at]||=[]; result[m.start_at] << m.events}